# minishlink web push not working

Tags: php, push-notification, push, web-push

I have this code and trying to var dump my res but am not getting anything, i have installed minishlink web push in my root directory and this is my code plz check

**send_push.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("php_includes/conn.php");

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
  }

$sam= "SELECT endpoint,p256dh,auth FROM endpointurl WHERE userid = ? ";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sam);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($endpoint,$p256dh,$key);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();



$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'https://*****.com',
        'publicKey' => '*********',
        'privateKey' => '*************', // in the real world, this would be in a secret file
    ),
);
//exit($subscriber['endpoint'].' : '.$subscriber['auth'].' : '.$subscriber['p256dh']);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);//some problem here

echo $endpoint ;//not even echoing this


$res = $webPush->sendNotification(
    $endpoint,
    '{"title":"hello","msg":"yes it works","icon":"/icons/cam.png","badge":"/icons/cam.png","url":"https://*****.com"}',
    str_replace(['_', '-'], ['/', '+'],$p256dh),
    str_replace(['_', '-'], ['/', '+'],$key),
    true
);

var_dump($res) ;
```

it is not even echoing $endpoint after creating a new webpush();

Comment: the error you shown means you are not using API correctly (like paramters to send and type of values need to be send). check the documentation of `API` and see some sample input example.Now compare with your input and rectify accordingly

Comment: yeah am trying that in other hand but everything looks fine when matched my code to api examples, is the error cause i installed api in root and not specifying it in the first line? should i add ..\ to it i tried this not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe u can try to put this foreach after sendNotification function.

```
foreach ($webPush->flush() as $report) {}
```

You can leave the foreach empty or you can debug the foreach if you want

```
foreach ($webPush->flush() as $report) {
    $endpoint = $report->getRequest()->getUri()->__toString();
    if ($report->isSuccess()) {
        $result = "[v] Message sent successfully for subscription {$endpoint}.";
    } else {
        $result = "[x] Message failed to sent for subscription {$endpoint}: {$report->getReason()}";
    }
}
```